# LWC event target data attributes propagation not working in Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning-web-components

In a parent LWC component I am using a child LWC component like so

```
<c-comp key={stuff.id} data-name={stuff.name} parameters={stuff.parameters} onresultavailable={handleResultAvailable}/>
```

and from the child LWC component I am triggering a Custom Event like the following:

```
    this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('resultavailable', {
          detail: {
            data: body,
            success: successful
          }
        })
    );
```

In the parent I can correctly access the event target data (for example event.target.dataset.name) fields when working in local dev server, but it doesn't work when running the component in the org. Should I configure the event in a different way, and if not, should I instead pass that element as field in the detail event (and how, then?)

Comment: What's the data type for "body"? The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch) says "The CustomEvent interface imposes no type requirements or structure on the detail property. However it’s important to send only primitive data. JavaScript passes all data types by reference except for primitives. If a component includes an object in its detail property, any listener can mutate that object without the component’s knowledge".

Comment: Additionally, your code sample has "data" but your explanation for parent says you read "dataset". Is that simply a mistake in the question? Do you not use the `event.detail.X` properties?

Comment: data correctly propagates, it's event.target.dataset.name that does not propagate

Comment: Is this "dataset" an API property on the child? (I think you should [edit] the question to clarify what "dataset" is and how it is declared.)

Comment: It's an html standard, see https://salesforcediaries.com/2020/02/28/how-to-handle-multiple-lightning-input-with-a-single-onchange-event-handler-in-lightning-web-component/ for example

Comment: OK, I'd not come across this before. I'll leave it to someone else to answer :D